# Injeção de dependencia de subprojeto .jar

Tags: java, cdi, ejb

Tenho uma aplicação `EJB` que possui uma `lib jar` como dependência construída para reutilização de código. O meu .jar possui uma classe que foi anotada com `@RequestScoped`, e eu preciso recupera-la no meu ejb.

Estou usando a seguinte linha, alguém sabe porque não funciona?

```
MinhaClasse o = CDI.current().select(MinhaClasse .class).get();
return o.getNome();
```

Código de erro:

```
  Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: class br.com.meuprojeto.jpa.MinhaClasse; Qualifiers: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classe MinhaClasse não está elegível para o CDI.

1. Verifique se está utilizando o @RequestScoped do CDI
   (javax.enterprise.context).
2. Utilize @Inject para realizar a injeção. Como um EJB é gerenciado
   pelo container, o Bean será injetado normalmente.
3. Certifique-se que seu JAR tem o arquivo beans.xml na pasta META-INF.

Caso nada disto resolva, você ainda pode criar um método anotado com @Produces que retorna uma instancia da classe MinhaClasse. Como o parametro do método você pode receber o que for necessário para criação da instancia (os itens recebidos por parâmetro tem que estarem elegiveis para o CDI).

Comment: A sua resposta solucionou
O meu JAR não tinha o xml beans.xml

Ao adiciona-lo a classe passou a ser reconhecida.

Comment: @SilasdeMoraes Ok, que bom que ajudou :). Por favor marque a resposta como a solução e se possível vote nela. Isto me ajudará a crescer aqui no stackoverflow. :D